# Implementing barcode scanner with help of ZXing

Tags: java, android, zxing

I want to implement ZXing open source barcode scanner in my project and I am following the steps from [here](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/), but I am stuck at step 4, I don't see ZXing in library section.

I have done all the above steps correctly

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the barcode scanner app.. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en

the intent will call up the app, scan the barcode, then the App will feed back the result into intent activity result

Comment: Isin't their any other way to integrate the scanner inside my App, other than user has to install two Apps and my issue is something different here

Comment: You will need to write your own scanner then (open up the camera, get the picture and send it to the ZXing decoder). ZXing only library to decode barcode image stream.

Comment: Sample implementation to decode QR Code from image stream http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader.java

Answer (score 1):

> I am stuck at step 4, I don't see ZXing in library section.

Quoting the blog entry:

> Right-click on ZXing project –> properties –> Android –> Scroll down and check/tick the “Is Library” checkbox –> OK.

After that, Step #4 should work properly.

Comment: @SamratMazumdar: Well, that's all that is needed for Step #4 to work. Hence, either you did not actually do it, or something is messed up in your environment. Confirm that your `project.properties` of the ZXing library contains `android.library=true`.